# How can I get the DVD title when all I have is a physical disc?

Tags: .net

(Using .NET)

1. User puts DVD in the drive.
2. Program shows the title of the DVD movie and maybe even some links to web info

Do DVDs have a "fingerprint" like music CD which can be used in a webservice lookup or is there embedded metadata on the DVD itself?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576372/identifying-cds

Comment: @Henrik: Which applies to CDs, not DVDs that the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DirectShowLib [From Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/) It has sample to handling the DVD.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I've looked at the source and samples from the DirectShowLib project and I can't see how it can help me get the title (as in the name of the movie) from a physical DVD.

Comment: Download DirectShowNet library sample from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/ then under the player there is solution called Dvdplay u can get all the information about DVD

Comment: Information such as as audio type and track is of no interest to me, the question was to get the name of the movie from the physical DVD - it doesn't look like the library can do that. Prove me wrong with an example line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Gracenote has a [CDDB-like service for DVDs](http://www.gracenote.com/products/videoid).

[Here is another service that operates like CDDB for DVDs.](http://www.dvd-db.dk/Main.asp)

Microsoft has a [service](http://metaservices.windowsmedia.com/dvdwizard/DVDWizard.asp?mode=SEARCH) to look up by title, but I'm not sure if it's possible to obtain the title from metadata on the DVD itself.

Comment: Links appear to be broken.  Sad panda.

Comment: @DanEsparza: updated the Gracenote link, but it looks like the other site may be down for good.